# Co-finite Topologies

Tags: general-topology

I would like someone to look through my solution to this problem and let me know if I have it correct or if I need to change anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
[image: question 3]
[image: Solution]

Comment: By the way, the cofinite topology has the interesting property that any set is compact under that topology.

Comment: Your proofs look fine. Pretty decent style for a student at that stage, actually.

Answer (score 1):

(b)  If U,V are open disjoint sets, then exist
finite sets A,B with U = X - A, V = X - B.
Since (X - A) $\cap$ (X - B) is empty,
X = A $\cup$ B is finite, by DeMorgan's rules.